# Speed Up Hot Folder Data Upload

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app, sap-commerce-cloud, hotfolder

I have CSV file of around 188MB. When I try to upload data using hot folder technique its taking too much time 10-12 hrs. How can I speedup the data upload?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Default value of `impex.import.workers` is `1`. Try to change this value. And I recommend making performance test with a bit smaller file first, than 188Mb (just to get swift results)

> Adjust the number of impex threads on the backoffice server to speed up ImpEx file processing. It is recommended that you start with it equal to the number of cores available on a backoffice node. You should not adjust it any higher than 2 * number of cores, and this is only if the IMPEX processes will be the only item running on the node. The actual value could be somewhere in between and will only be determined by testing and analyzing the number of other processes, jobs, apps running on your server to ensure you are not maxing out CPU.
>   NOTE: this value could be higher for lower environments since Hybris will likely be the only process running.

Taken from [Tuning Parameters - Hybris Wiki](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/hybrisALF/Hybris+Tuning)